# How to make negation of value based on condition

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, looker-studio

I have need to negate number based on value in column. Id like to perform this task either in google sheets or preferably directly in Looker studio.

**Current state:**

| Column_A | Column_B | Column_C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Cell A | Purchase | 5 |
| Cell B | Return | 4 |
| Cell B | Purchase | 3 |
| Cell A | Return | 6 |

**Expected state:**

| Column_A | Column_B | Column_D |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Cell A | Purchase | 5 |
| Cell B | Return | -4 |
| Cell B | Purchase | 3 |
| Cell A | Return | -6 |

Basically I want to condition value in Column C to be negative if the word in Column B gonna a be a specific word.

**Wrong idea:**
CASE
WHEN column_B = "Purchase" THEN column_d *(-1)
ELSE "n/a"
ENSE

Thank you for any idea!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use:

```
CASE WHEN Column_B='Return' THEN Column_C*-1 ELSE Column_C END
```

- 

[image]